# Proving that the limit of the following sequence $\frac {\sqrt {n}}{1 + \sqrt{n}}$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ is 1.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Proving that the limit of the following sequence:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sqrt {n}}{1 + \sqrt{n}} = 1$$

I have selected the $N$ to be $\lfloor (\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1)^2 \rfloor + 1$, am I right?

Comment: Are u employing $\epsilon-\delta$ method or, you are interested in another version?

Comment: You could think of $\frac{n}{1+n}$ instead. It is completely ok here.

Comment: Is there any requirement that $N$ actually be a natural number.  After all you need to show something for all natural $n > N$ but $N$ itself has not role other than as a hurdle for the natural $n$ to exceed.  And $n$ can be greater than  a real number just as well as being greater than a natural number.

Comment: tl;dr.   It's perfectly fine to just say  "Let $N$ but any natural number larger than $(1/\epsilon - 1)^2$".  No need to futz with the floor or indexing.

Comment: @fleablood In the definition that I am using for the limit $N$ should be a positive integer, this is why I am using the floor.

Comment: Fair enough.  But you don't actually have to identify and name in integer that $N$ is.  It is good enough to simple say "Let $N$ be an integer so that $N \ge blah$".  You don't actually have to solve for $N$.  (Although you did... and you did it correctly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$ \left|\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}} - 1\right| = \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}} , $$
so we want
$$ \frac{1}{1+\sqrt n} < \epsilon \iff \sqrt{n} > \frac{1}{\epsilon}-1 \iff n > \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon}-1 \right)^2, $$
so you can indeed take
$$ N = \left\lfloor \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon}-1 \right)^2 \right\rfloor + 1. $$

Comment: Good and enough+

Comment: @mrs Thanks, there might have been an error in my first version of the answer, since I did not take care that we want a strict inequality, so actually OP's choice of $N$ is better than the one I took.

Comment: There's no reason that $N$ must be a natural number; just that the $n \ge N$ is a natural number.  Likewise it's not clear if the OP's definition requires that $n \ge N$ or that $n > N$ and neither have any logistical imperitive. And there is no brownie points in finding the absolute minimum possible $N$. Any $n > (1/\epsilon - 1)^2$ will do.

Comment: @fleablood Of course not, but some authors take $N$ to be an integer when defining limits of sequences, and it seemed that OP was using such a definition.

Comment: My point is worrying about the precise value of $N$ is not really important.  If one $N$ will do then any larger $N$ will do just as well. so all we need is $N \ge (\frac 1\epsilon -1)^2$.  Futzing with floor and ceilings is ... well, picayune.  I mean, we don't have to *prove* there is an $N\ge (\frac 1\epsilon -1)^2$ (at least we never need to prove it more than once) we can merely state that there is one and that will do.

Comment: @fleablood I completely agree with you, but some exercises require you to find a specific value of $N$. Otherwise it really does not matter.

Comment: Well, then I guess the OP got  it (better than I would have) if his requirement is for all $n \ge N$.  If it's for all $n > N$ then the $N$ should be the ceiling with no offset.  Anyhow... I suppose I should acknowledge the OP being correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have it.

We know $0 < \sqrt n < 1+ \sqrt n$ so $\frac {\sqrt n}{1 + \sqrt n} <1$ so we need to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ then there is an $N$ so the $n > N$ would imply

$0< 1 - \frac {\sqrt n}{1 + \sqrt n} < \epsilon$

And $1 - \frac {\sqrt n}{1 + \sqrt n} < \epsilon \iff$

$(1 + \sqrt n) - \sqrt n= 1 < \epsilon(1+\sqrt n) \iff $

$\frac 1{\epsilon} -1 < \sqrt n$.  Wolog we may assume $\epsilon < 1$. If we prove it is true for any $0 < \epsilon_1 < 1$ then the same $N$ will work for any *larger* $\epsilon \ge \epsilon_1$.  So if we assumme $0 < \epsilon < 1$ then $\frac 1{\epsilon} > 1$ and

$\frac 1{\epsilon} -1 < \sqrt n \iff$

$(\frac 1{\epsilon} -1)^2 < n$ so

So for any $N \ge (\frac 1{\epsilon} -1)^2$ we will have that if $n > N$ then $0< 1 - \frac {\sqrt n}{1 + \sqrt n} < \epsilon$.

So, ... Okay, I'd have picked the *ceiling* of $(\frac 1{\epsilon} -1)^2$ and there's no brownie points in figuring the exact *minimum* $N$ we can choose.

But yes if $N = \lfloor (\frac 1{\epsilon} -1)^2 \rfloor < n$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ then $n \ge N+1 >  (\frac 1{\epsilon} -1)^2$ and therefore $0< 1 - \frac {\sqrt n}{1 + \sqrt n} < \epsilon$.

So yes.  Using the floor will work and is correct.  And so will *any* $N$ greater than the floor.

Actually, is there *any* requirement in your definition that $N$ must actually be a natural number?  There is no logistical requirement for this if you think about it.  After all it is $n > N$ that must be natural.   The $N$ is just a hurdle and there's no reason that can't just be some real magnitude.

So actually, I'd just choose $N = (\frac 1{\epsilon} -1)^2$ and be done with.

Answer (score 1):

As

$$\frac{\sqrt n}{1+\sqrt n}-1=\frac1{1+\sqrt n},$$ which is a decreasing function, you can work this out by solving the equation

$$\frac1{1+\sqrt x}=\epsilon,$$ the solution of which is obviously

$$x=\left(\frac1\epsilon-1\right)^2.$$

Now you want the first integer $n$ strictly larger than $x$, and this is $\lfloor x\rfloor+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n)$
be a increasing
positive sequence
such that,
for any $c > 0$,
there is an $N(c)$
such that
$f(N(c)) > c$.

Then,
for any reals $a$ and $b$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(n)+a}{f(n)+b}
=1$.

Proof.

$\dfrac{f(n)+a}{f(n)+b}-1
=\dfrac{(f(n)+a)-(f(n)+b)}{f(n)+b}
=\dfrac{a-b}{f(n)+b}
$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$
we want an $n$ such that
$|\dfrac{a-b}{f(n)+b}|
\le \epsilon$.

This will be true if
$\dfrac{|a-b|}{f(n)-|b|}
\le \epsilon
$
or
$|a-b|
\le \epsilon(f(n)-|b|)
$
or
$f(n)
\ge \dfrac{|a-b|}{\epsilon}+|b|
$.

Therefore,
if 
$n > N(\dfrac{|a-b|}{\epsilon}+|b|)
$,
$|\dfrac{f(n)+a}{f(n)+b}-1|
\lt \epsilon
$,
so
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(n)+a}{f(n)+b}
= 1$.

Now let
$a=0, b=1,
f(n) = \sqrt{n}$.
We can choose
$N(c) = c^2+1$.